# How to close a form modal by clicking enter using bootstrap and angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

There is a submit button when I click on it modal is closing and form gets submitted
Now in the same way when i click on enter in input field modal should be closed and form should be submitted

I tried using some methods but form is submitting but modal is not closing

Comment: just add a modal closing call inside of a submit handler

Comment: The docs describe multiple ways you can close a modal: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#usage

Comment: Your question is : How to bind keyboard enter with submit action (which close the modal) ? response below

Answer (score 0):

in the .html add keyup.enter event binding in your submit button

```
<button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()" (keyup.enter)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

In the .ts

```
onSubmit() {
    // submit logic
    // close the modal 
}
```

Comment: a button type submit (In angular by defect all the buttons are type submit) is always execute the click if you use "enter", so it's unnecessary add (keyup.enter)